# concatenate two fields and copy to another one

Tags: contacts

For each contacts of a given sub type (subtype = child) we need to concatenate to set the external identifier as the concatenation of lastname & first name.
We are doing this by exporting to excel, concatenate in excel and then import. It works but is time consuming and cannot be scheduled to run every 24 hours for example.

Is there a way to

1. set external identifier = concatenate(Last name, First name)
2. run this periodically in some way, or even better : each time firt or last name is modified ?

Comment: why do you need this? is it possible you could just do this using tokens when you need it, rather than having it saved in the db itself?

Comment: or eg use 'postal greeting' field for it again using tokens

Comment: Very good question @petednz-fuzion. The root cause for this need is an issue that I wanted to ask about since  a long time, I've just published 
[this question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/42678/create-relationships-using-profiles-or-forms)

Would love to have your experienced opinion about it :)

Comment: i see someone else has already pointed to Caldera

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement api and/or hook to update via cron job and/or when contact is updated via custom extension

Comment: thx Pradeep !
So it's not so easy but I'll explore this good idea