# create relationships using profiles or forms

Tags: profile, relationships

To make a long story short, before all the details below : our CMS is wordpress, and creating relationships between contacts (parent-child) using profiles seems not possible. It was with Caldera Form, it is with Drupal, which is not an option for us.
Is there a nice solution to this problem? Knowing that we don't have any developper in our organization...

---

**Details about the (bad but working) workaround we use**

We use Civicrm to manage a database of contacts which are parents and their children.

We have custom fields on child subtype : school name, level, class number

Using profiles and civimail, we encourage parents to update by themselves their own contact details and of their children : less admin work for us.

According to what I have read, with WordPress + Civi, it not possible to create a relationship between 2 individuals by filling in a profile.
We would love that when a parent enters the first and last name of his child, then the child contact is automatically created or updated, and a relationship is created between parent and child.
We could not find a way to do this (I read that it was possible in the past with Caldera form, or today with Drupal)

So we use a workaround which is time consuming and not efficient, described below.

**BEGIN**

A) on the contacts where sub-type=parent, we created custom data like this :

- child 1 : first name, last name, school name, etc...
- child 2 : first name, last name, school name, etc...
- child 3 : first name, last name, school name, etc...

B) We also create in bulk the children by mass uploading the  listing provided by the school
In this mass upload, we set the external identifer of each children as the concatenation of last name and first name, and remove all accents, upper case, blanks, etc... : in order to normalize the data for step C) below

Example : BAKER Paul-émile has bakerpaulemile as external identifer

C) then the ugly part is how to create the relationships between parents and children

From time to time and manually, we export parents to excel, and from child 1 custom fields, we concatenate lastname and first name as above, put that in a csv file next to the parent email, then upload the csv to  create the relationship.
Then same for children2 and children3

**END**

It works, but I hate this solution :( It's a nightmare.

Does anyone has a better idea, knowing that Drupal is not an option for us ?

To make things a bit easier, we are wondering if there is a way to populate a custom field automatically as the concatenatation of first & last name, removing accents. Which is why we asked [that other question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/42660/concatenate-two-fields-and-copy-to-another-one)

Comment: Have you looked at https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/caldera-civicrm, the successor to caldera forms?

Comment: Wow, no I didn't know this was a reality ! Will explore this, which sounds promising, thanks a lot !