# Formbuilder relationships - Autofill several relationships

Tags: relationships, formbuilder

### **Summary**

This is a follow up question of [that one](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/42678/create-relationships-using-profiles-or-forms), that I asked a year ago when FormBuilder was not as advanced as today. There was no easy solution, now there is almost one, so a big thx and congrats to the FormBuilder developpers :)

Our use case is probably very common : a form where a parent can fill in his own data and the data of his two children, with "parent of / child of" relationships.

We would like the names and data of the parent and related children to be auto-filled, if already present in Civicrm, and this is where we are **failing for the second child**.

- Parent autofill : ok
- Child 1 autofill : ok
- Child 2 autofill : NOT ok, it is autofilled with the data of Child 1 :(

---

### Details

This form seems to work as expected to create new parent and children from a blank form

[image]

Then we use the email token in Civimail, so that existing Parents can update their data and children.The email token is `{afform.afformTestLink}`

[image]

Autofill is working ok for the parent, and one child

**For Parent1 :**

[image]

**For Child 1**: "child of / current user"
[image]

**For Child 2**: same as child 1, although the parent as 2 different children already related to him in civicrm

[image]

### PROBLEM

child 2 is autofilled with the same data as child 1 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of @Coleman above was perfect, I could even do more than expected.
Detailed solution below.

Tabs in the form :

- parents
- related children
- relationship

Related children are autofilled as "Child of current user", and made a repeating entity

[image]

[image]

Parents are autofilled as "Parent of related children", and also repeating entity.
With this trick, we get the data of the other parent :)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well articulated question!
I noticed in your screenshot that you have 2 child entities on the form. They are both being filled in the same way, so they both get the same result. Not what you want, but I understand why the computer would do that .

I think you might get your desired result if you only have 1 child entity on the form, and make it a repeating entity. If you still want a maximum of 2 you can configure a limit to the repeat setting.

Comment: thx a lot @Coleman for your answer, it worked! I have detailed the solution with screenshots.
Since then I have been struggling with 2 problems (bugs) using search kit + autofill + autocomplete (using them as a workaround to this [Deduper](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45405/deduper-fails-with-punctations-in-the-name-dot-semicolon-underscore-parenthe) issue)
Would highly appreciate your feedback about these 2 :

Comment: PROBLEM 1 : [error (infinite loop ?) when using formbuilder + autofill + autocomplete existing user](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45414/error-infinite-loop-when-using-formbuilder-autofill-autocomplete-existin)

Comment: PROBLEM 2:
[error when using formbuilder + autocomplete existing user + sub-type](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45413/error-when-using-formbuilder-autocomplete-existing-user-sub-type)