# Deduper fails with punctations in the name (dot, semicolon, underscore, parenthesis...)

Tags: duplicate-contacts, issues, dedupe-rules

As per this [documentation page](https://docs.civicrm.org/deduper/en/latest/resolvers/) of the [Deduper extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/deduper), *the Uninformative characters resolver* should be able to detect names such as O.Donel / O Donel / O;Donel as duplicates, but after testing, I can't make it work as expected.
I might be doing something wrong. ? Can anyone make a very simple test and try to reproduce the issue ?
Scenario :

- create 2 contacts with first name = John | Last name = ODonel | email=test@test.com
- confirm that Deduper detects them as duplicate, using the "Name and Email" standard rule

[image]

- then introduce small variations in the last names, such as O_Donel / O Donel / O.Donel / O;Donel : this is where Deduper fails at finding duplicates. I have tried the following combinations :

Contact 1 / Contact 2

ODonel / O_Donel

O;Donel / O_Donel (as per the [php code of the extension](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/deduper/-/blob/master/CRM/Deduper/BAO/Resolver/UninformativeCharactersResolver.php) characters such as  _ ; are removed for comparison purpose)

and many others, with no luck

Thx !

> The Uninformative characters resolver. This strips a range of white
> space and punctuation characters out when comparing names. Currently
> the list is hard coded but I'm open to making it configurable. It also
> has a shorter list of characters that it will strip only if that
> resolves the conflict. For example a '.' is stripped in the
> uninformative characters resolver as that will mean later the initial
> resolver has a better chance of working.

Comment: Have you tried testing on dmaster.demo.civicrm.org? The demo site is reset frequently, so is a good place to try out things to make sure it's not just something on your end. You can add the Deduper extension as usual on the demo site.

Comment: Thx a lot for the advice, I didn't know this. Just tested on dmaster, same result as on my server. So it looks like a bug on Deduper extension from my point of view....

Comment: [Issue opened](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/deduper/-/issues/1#note_150120)