# error when using formbuilder + autocomplete existing user + sub-type

Tags: searchkit, formbuilder, sub-types, autocomplete

### Summary

Our use case is probably very common : a form where a parent can fill in his own data and the data of his children, with "parent of / child of" relationships.
In order to avoid creation of duplicate children and because we have found out that Deduper does not work if there is an hyphen in the name, we use a workaround using Searchkit + Autocomplete + Formbuilder, so that parents can pick up their children already existing in our civicrm.

Problem: if we add a value "sub-type=child" in formbuilder, then autocomplete does not work.

Bug ? Missing feature ? Something wrong in our setup ?

### Details

**Searchkit** : a basic contact search, where sub-type = child

[image]

**Autocomplete in Searchkit** : a basic configuration showing the full name of the child. Works well in preview in Searchkit / Autocomplete page

**Formbuilder**
A basic form with individual (multiple),  a search box "existing user", leveraging the autocomplete described above. In open access.
The problem is caused by the red rectangle on the screenshot below.

When using the form, the search does not work : no user is found.

If we remove "sub-type"= child (the red rectangle), then :

- the search / autocomplete works
- BUT as a drawback, if the child does not existing in our civicrm and the parent creates it (entering last name and surname of the child), then it is created as an Individual **without** sub-type=Child, which is a problem

[image]

Comment: I found a workaround : in searchkit, instead of `Sub-Type=child`, we use `Sub-Type<>Parent and Sub-Type Not Empty`
This is not ideal (especially if you have many subtypes), but it works on v 5.62.1


Is this a bug ?