# error (infinite loop ?) when using formbuilder + autofill + autocomplete existing user

Tags: searchkit, formbuilder, autocomplete

### Summary

Our use case is probably very common : a form where a parent can fill in his own data and the data of his children, with "parent of / child of" relationships.

In order to avoid creation of duplicate children (and because we have found out that Deduper does not work if there is an hyphen in the name), we use a workaround with Searchkit + Autocomplete + Formbuilder, so that parents can pick up their children already existing in our civicrm.

Problem: if we use autofill to display the children already with a "child of" relationship, then the content of some fields blink and changes endlessly

Bug ? Missing feature ? Something wrong in our setup ?

### Details

**Searchkit** : a basic contact search, where sub-type = child

[image]

**Autocomplete in Searchkit** : a basic configuration showing the full name of the child. Works well in preview in Searchkit / Autocomplete page

**Formbuilder**
A basic form with individual (multiple),  a search box "existing user", leveraging the autocomplete described above. In open access.
Autofill : child of current user

[image]

[image]

What happens : on screenshot below, the content of the red field alternate very rapidely (creating a "blinking" effect) between :

- empty
- 9845 (which is the contact ID of Bart Simpson)
- Bart Simpson

[image]

Then if we click on "add" to creation an additional child, it gets worse : the 3 yellow fields have the same blinking / alternating problem, their content cycle between Bart Simpson and Lisa Simpson (the 2 children)

[image]

Then if in the green box we select "Hugo Simpson", then the yellow fields have the blinking / alternating problem, they cycle between Hugo and Lisa (note that Bart seems to have disappeared ;). And the name fields below the green field remain empty

Comment: Which version of CiviCRM are you using?

Comment: 5.62.1 (I should have said that in the original question, sorry ;)

Comment: Could you please try again on the latest (5.64+)? IIRC there have been some fixes in this area recently.

Comment: I have just reproduced the problem on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/test
v 5.66.alpha1

I guess dmaster will be reset in about an hour, but if you connect to this URL  before with the demo admin account, you will see the problem

Comment: You're right the demo site didn't last long enough but I'll try to reproduce based on your screenshots...

Answer (score 2):

That was indeed a bug in FormBuilder. Multiple bugs in fact. I've fixed them all in this PR: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/27121

You can help by reviewing the PR, you'll find instructions for doing so right under the description (in the comment posted by CiviBot).